# android studio 3.2 preview gradle sync failed but build success

Tags: android-studio-3.2

Build/Sync window showed the 'CONFIGURE SUCCESSFUL' and Build Successful.
But the android studio still show the error: "Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality will not work properly"

Answer (score 6):

Update at 2019/01/15

Update android studio to 3.3 fix this problem!

---

I face this too.
Not a solve, but you can try.

1. In your project gradle file

change gradle version from 3.2.0 to 3.1.4

`com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4`

2. In gradle-wrapper.properties file

change gradle version from 4.6 to 4.4

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip`

Comment: Is it works now without this manipulations? I still have this bug with 3.2.1 and 4.6.

Comment: @kolombo Sorry, I have no idea about that. I am still using this method. Hope google fix this in next version.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was there was no google() in my repo list under all projects:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```